# How to solve "Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort2, was issued."

Tags: windows-10, drivers, ssd

About once a day I am seeing a process (not always the same one) lock up in a way that I cannot even kill it and I need to restart windows (10) to free it up.

Each time this happens it is accompanied by the error "Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort2, was issued." in the System Event Logs...

All my drives are Samsung SSDs and I have verified that they are all in good condition via Samsung Magician tools.

I have tried the suggestion related to disable some power management settings as in [this forum post](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Reset-to-device-Device-RaidPort0-was-issued-Event-id-129/m-p/4657366/highlight/true#M861319)

I have ensured that all my drivers are update date and my ASUS B350M bios is up to date etc. and have tried both installing and uninstalling Intel Rapid Storage Device.

Anyone had this problem and found a fix?

**UPDATE**: Since that link is for the Dell forum and one needs to register/login to see it, here is what it said (and what I have tried)

> First of all we need to change "AHCI Link Power Management" which is a hidden setting on power management. Open up registry editor and change the following settings.
>
> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442\0b2d69d7-a2a1-449c-9680-f91c70521c60
>
> Change attributes from 1 to 2
>
> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442\dab60367-53fe-4fbc-825e-521d069d2456
>
> And again change Attributes from 1 to 2.
>
> Now go to Control Panel -> System and Security -> Power Options click on "Change Plan Settings" and then click on "Change advanced Power settings".
>
> Now under "Hard disk" you should have AHCI Link Power Management - HIPM/DIPM and AHCI Link Power Management - Adaptive options.
>
> Change "AHCI Link power management" To active, which means there is no power management for AHCI and finally change Adaptive to 0 milliseconds (Although if you enabled "active" this option has no effect).
>
> Finally under "PCI Express" Change "Link State Power management" to OFF.

Comment: That forum link is broken for me. Is "AHCI Link Power Management - HIPM/DIPM" enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: Aaah sorry - I think one has to log into the Dell site to see that

Comment: I don't have that option... but nearest I can see is "sata mode selection" = "AHCI" and "Aggressive LPM support" = "disabled"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So.... turned out to be a problem with my Power Supply.

It was not regulating properly any more and under certain loads was spiking the hardware.

This resulted in the SSDs (which are good quality Samsung ones) shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

**Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort2, was issued.**  >>> could be this caused by me connecting 3 external USB drives via single USB port?
I moved one hdd now to another USB port as I suspect this particular error comes from too much power on single USB.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).